# C++ using operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


class   matrix   

{

private:

    int row;

    int col;

    int **data;

public:

    matrix(int r=0,int c=0)

    {
        row=r;
        col=c;
        data=new int*[row];
        for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
            data[i]=new int [col];
        }
    }

    friend void createMatrix (int row, int col, int num[], matrix& mat);

    friend istream &operator>>(istream&in,matrix &mat);

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&out,matrix &mat);

    matrix operator+ (matrix mat)
    {
        matrix z(row,col);
        if((row==mat.row)&&(col==mat.col))
        {
            for(int i=0 ; i<row ; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0 ; j<col; j++)
                {
                    z.data[i][j]=data[i][j]+mat.data[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Matrix that aren't the same size can't be added"<<endl;
        }
        return z;
    }        

};                   

 ostream &operator<<(ostream&out,matrix &mat)        

{

    for(int i=0; i<mat.row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<mat.col; j++)
        {
            out<<mat.data[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        out<<endl;
    }
    return out;
}

istream &operator >>(istream &in,matrix& mat)

{

    cout<<"Enter the size of your matrix"<<endl;
    in>>mat.row;
    in>>mat.col;
    mat.data=new int*[mat.row];
    cout<<"Enter the elements of your matrix"<<endl;
    for(int x=0; x<mat.row; x++)
    {
        mat.data[x]=new int[mat.col];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<mat.row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<mat.col; j++)
        {
            in>>mat.data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return in;
}

int main()

{

    matrix x,y;

    cin>>x>>y;
    cout<<x+y<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void createMatrix (int row, int col, int num[], matrix& mat)

{

    mat.row = row;
    mat.col = col;
    mat.data = new int* [row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        mat.data[i] = new int [col];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            mat.data[i][j] = num[i * col + j];
}
```

When I try to run, I get the error:

```
|83|error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'matrix')|
```

but when I change the main to:

```
matrix x,y,z;
cin>>x>>y;
z=x+y;
cout<<z<<endl;
return 0;
```

I get no problems although I can't use that because I have to do about 14 different operator overloading I'm not sure if i'ts a code error or a compiler error. Any idea what I can do to solve it?

Comment: Please format the code better

Answer (score 2):

You have defined your `operator<<` to take a matrix reference

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream&out,matrix &mat)
```

while the output of the expression

```
x+y
```

is a temporary object that cannot be passed as a reference. You must either pass it as a const reference `const matrix& mat` or by value `matrix mat`. In this case, you should use a const reference, to avoid copying the whole matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Use a const matrix:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream&out,const matrix &mat)
```

This creates a temporary matrix

```
cout<<x+y<<endl;
```

It cannot be passed by ref only. And as it is for output, it should be const ref anyway.

Comment: As well as modifying the signature in `friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&out, const matrix &mat);` to add `const`

Comment: Of course, both declarations have to be changed indeed.